# Textboxfor field not submitting uppercase characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form where I put the following style on the textboxfor field for registering a username.

```
   #upper {

        text-transform: uppercase;

    }
```

The css style works and everything I type outputs as an uppercase character, but when I submit the form, the stored value in the database is lowercase for some reason.
I can't figure out how to keep it uppercase like how it outputs in the textboxfor field. 
Any help is appreciated.

for

```
 <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", style = "font-size:13px; font-weight:bold" })

                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", id = "upper", maxlength = 6, style = "width:300px" })
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: If your requirement is to make sure the text is uppercase before saving to database, how about you add a `.ToUpper()` in your code behind before saving to database?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add a .ToUpper to an aplicationdbcontext value, but I found a workaround. It's outputting into a datatable so I wrapped the output around a div and styled it with the  text-transform: uppercase; How would I add .ToUpper to an aplicationdbcontext field? Could you show an example?

Comment: What @degant is saying is to call `ToUpper` on the property in your action *after* the post but *before* saving, i.e. `model.Username = model.Username.ToUpper();`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is just that - the CSS is simply a **style**. It doesn't transform the actual underlying text to upper case, it just **shows** it like that in the browser. This is something you can check in your browser dev tools.

If someone types "help", you see "Help", but underneath it is **still** "help" and would submit as such.

If the text is typed as "Help", that's what will be submitted.